# Yii2 GroupUrlRule with language prefix

Tags: php, yii2

My website has a language prefix for every link. Example

```
www.mysite.com/en/myfirstmodule/home
www.mysite.com/fr/myfirstmodule/
www.mysite.com/en/myothermodule/about
```

How can I use GroupUrlRule.php with the language prefix? Having something like this won't work because GroupUrlRule.php prefix cannot have a pattern.

```
'rules' => [
    new GroupUrlRule([
        'prefix'=>'<lang:(en|fr|ar)>/myfirstmodule',
            'rules'=>[
                ...
            ],
        ]),
    ],
   ...
]
```